# Is there a way to get list, out of the list of pairs effectively splitting a list into two by pair in C++

Tags: c++, std

Would it be possible to split a list of pairs into two separate lists?

My list:

`std::list<std::pair<Shape*, std::string>> listOfShapes;`

So I would like to get a list of strings out of listOfShapes, but without using any for loops.

Thanks :)

Comment: Applying two `std::transform()` may be? Anything you already have coded or researched yet?

Comment: The loops would be internal to the C++ standard library (perhaps cheating therefore?), but you can probably concoct this with `std::transform` and an appropriate lambda. Doing it in one traversal with a tuple as the return type would be particularly smart. But that would require C++17. Upvoting the question, wishing for someone to answer. The latter is above my pay grade.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. Only a loop can do this, either your own or the one you call from an appropriate C++ library algorithm.

Comment: thanks for the explanations, I solved it with std::transform :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that (not tested, but compilable):

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

class Shape;
std::list<std::pair<Shape*, std::string>> listOfShapes;

std::list<Shape*> list1;
std::list<std::string> list2;

template<typename F, typename S>
class Split {
public:
    using value_type = std::pair<F, S>;
    Split(std::list<F> &f, std::list<S> &s) : f_(f), s_(s) {};
    void push_back(const std::pair<F, S>& value ) {
        f_.push_back(value.first);
        s_.push_back(value.second);
    }
private:
    std::list<F> &f_;
    std::list<S> &s_;
};

Split<Shape*, std::string> s(list1, list2);
auto e = std::copy(listOfShapes.begin(), listOfShapes.end(), std::back_insert_iterator<Split<Shape*, std::string> >(s));
```

Comment: thanks for your example, but eventually I solved it with std::transform :)